# How does C# handle historical daylight saving time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc, dst

EU is planning to stop DST so I began to wonder how this will reflect in our code. For example let's say there will be no DST from 2021, while now it is. Let's say we are in `UTC+1` now in winter time and in `UTC+2` during summer.

Then `2019-06-01T12:00:00` local time will be converted `2019-06-01T10:00:00Z` in UTC.

Now if we will do exactly the same in 2025 when summer time is `UTC+1` and all operating systems/frameworks will upgrade to know there is no DST anymore. Which result will the example conversion yield (it will be historical date time by that point)?

I would think that it will be handled by new rules, so the result will be `2019-06-01T10:00:00Z`, but perhaps it somehow will know that was `2019-06-01T10:00:00Z` back then?

Comment: Store dates as UTC ...but show them as local time ...then there would be no problem (as framework/icu should take care of it)

Comment: Well it's just the same problem upside down. If we store it UTC and then convert a UTC date in 2019 and in 2025, will the result be the same? (time of the day or not)

Comment: Non serious answer: ``if (date.Month > DayLightStartingMonth && date.Month < DayLightEndingMonth && some more conditions) ``

Comment: Store dates as UTC and let OS handle conversion to local time as OS has rules of DST dates.

Comment: I *highly* recomend using the [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) library to handle things like this, rather than the built in `DateTime` types.  While the built in types should be accurate, Noda Time will help you save your sanity,

Comment: [Interesting post from last year](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/handling-a-new-era-in-the-japanese-calendar-in-net/) discussing many internals (the context was a new Japenese era)

Comment: .NET just doesn't have anything to do with it, it is the job of the OS to keep track of DST change history.  It is not that good at predicting what politicians will decide in the future, updates are delivered through Windows Update.  Be sure to not make the mistake of calculating local times that are in the future, your politicians are going to disappoint you.